# Johns Garage.. Expected change in profit?

Tags: calculus

John’s garage is considering hiring another mechanic. With an additional mechanic, if there are a lot of accidents in San Jose this year, then John anticipates making an additional $75,000$ profit. However, if there are not a lot of accidents, then John’s garage could lose $\$20,000$ due to the salary/benefits for the additional mechanic. John thinks that there will be a $30\%$ chance of “ a lot of accidents” and a $70\%$ chance of “not a lot of accidents”. Assume if John’s garage doesn’t expand, then he will have the same profit as last year.

a. What is the expected change in profit (could be a gain or a loss) if John’s garage decides to hire another mechanic.

So far I have...  $0.3\times70000- 0.7\times20,000$

= $\$21,000- \$14,000= \$7000$.

Comment: Apart from $75000 in your question and 70000 in your calculation, your method is correct

Comment: Oh.. SO it would be 0.3 x 75000 - 0.7 x 20000?

Comment: Yes. The 70000 in your calculation must have just been a copying error, unless you meant to use that value?